# Intercept YouTube search

Tags: android, youtube, intercept

What I want is to give user the ability to run my application instead of default YouTube one when any application requests YouTube search. I've tried to play with `intent-filter`, but with no success. Intent looks like this (from DDMS): `Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.google.android.youtube cmp=com.google.android.youtube/.app.froyo.phone.ResultsActivity (has extras) } from pid 4766`. As you see, it contains no `data` field, so I can't easily add `<data>` element to my intent filter, as I do with URL interception.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Intent` that you have listed, it is impossible for you to "intercept" it, as it specifically identifies the component (`cmp=com.google.android.youtube/.app.froyo.phone.ResultsActivity`).

Comment: So isn't there any other way to intercept search request in default YouTube application? What if I create package with the same name in my app?

Comment: @chersanya: "So isn't there any other way to intercept search request in default YouTube application?" -- not if that is the `Intent` that they use. "What if I create package with the same name in my app?" -- you can't, because that is not your app.